# What is the name of this definition of the distance between two probability distributions?

Tags: probability, metric-spaces

There are many different definitions of the distance between two probability distributions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance . When P and Q are very similar, many of these converge (up to multiplication by a constant) on the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence . However, that is not a metric, because it is $O((P-Q)^2)$.

If we take the square-root of the KL divergence, we obtain a distance that can be used as a metric when $P$ and $Q$ are very similar. However, it is not a metric globally ( https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57725/is-the-square-root-of-the-symmetric-kullback-leibler-divergence-a-metric ).

We can make a global metric by integrating up the local metric. The result is the following:

$$A(P, Q) = \arccos\left( \sum_x { \sqrt{P(x)Q(x)} } \right).$$

What is this called?

Update 2013-11-14: As pointed out in the answers, this can be interpreted as the angle between unit vectors $\sqrt{P}$ and $\sqrt{Q}$.

Comment: Nice question. You might want to add a proof that A is indeed a metric.

Comment: there is a symmetric version of the KL div. doesnt it help?

Comment: No, the symmetric KL divergence is neither a metric nor even the square of a metric (see link in question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Martin-Fernandez et. al.'s [Measures of Difference for Compositional Data and Hierarchical Clustering Methods](http://ima.udg.edu/%7Ebarcelo/index_archivos/Measures_of_difference__Clustering.pdf) (pdf) it is referred to as the "Bhattacharyya ($\arccos$) distance".

> $$\displaystyle d(x_i, x_j) = \arccos \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{D} \sqrt{x_{ik} x_{jk}} \right )$$
>
> The Bhattacharyya ($\arccos$) distance between two compositions $x_i$ and $x_j$ can be interpreted as the angle between the unit vectors $\sqrt{x_i}$ and $\sqrt{x_j}$. This distance is directly related to the Matusita distance which is also known as the Hellinger distance.

Comment: So would you say that the Wikipedia page on Bhattacharyya distance is wrong?http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance

Comment: The distance on the Wikipedia entry appears to be presenting the "Bhattacharyya (log) distance" using the terminology from Martin-Fernandez et. al.

Comment: Hmmm. A 1-parameter family of names. This doesn't sound like a very canonical name! But I will award you the bounty if nothing better comes up. Thank you.